# A way to keep colors in black&white picture when changing image mode from index color to greyscale?

Tags: photoshop, grayscale

I took pics like these [image]

[image]
The files generated form the camera are bmp.

Problem is i need to load them in a certain program where i noticed works only when in photoshop i go to modes -> greyscale. The images are originally indexed color or RGB Color (which i used to make some adjustments - but end results is like u see in these pictures). But when i change mode to greyscale I notice the pics changing (though not sure because i mainly use the mean value from histogram to measure various areas with the square marquee tool -the mean value changes at around 10 points, but again unsure if i should be using that one or if there is some other way to measure the average value of a color in an area). But the image should remain same since its black&white right?

Comment: Going to greyscale, Photoshop adds colours with noise.

Comment: @Ghoul Fool given my pics are already shades of gray can I prevent that?

Comment: from RGB choose Image > Mode > Index Colour from the drop down palette menu (at the very top) choose custom and the from the next drop down, called Table, pick greyscale.

Comment: Or if you have an old version of Photoshop you can escape the grayscale noise! As it never used to occur. Must be an Adobe "feature"

Comment: oh thanks a lot mate, been cracking my head for several days with that. Now only need to see how to embed it into my script before saving the image as BMP (btw have photoshop CC 2019). Btw can u turn it into answer so i can upvote u? :)

Comment: This has been bugging me too. And I have the answer to why noise gets added. Its down to the greyscale colour profile. See the answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/146863/rgb-to-grayscale-without-adding-noise/146875#146875)

Comment: yeah i mean answer here to this post not with comment so i can mark it as accepted answer (if there is any extra gain for you in stackoverflow -karma points or whatever this page points system is). Again u spared me quite a bit of a headache so thanks a bunch :)